# changes to /etc/mail.rc does not seem to take effect

Tags: cron, mailx

there were some changes with our smtps server, specifically the port that we can use.

as I have done before, I changed the details in /etc/mail.rc file.

but when I run my script, there is a log in /var/log/messages that it cannot access port 465.

**crond: sendmail: Cannot open smtps4.company.com:465**

what I don't get though is that I already changed the port to 587, but the logs say it is trying to connect to port 465. Maybe I missed a file that also needs to be updated?

I restart my development computer whenever I try to change the config file mail.rc

Answer (score 0):

I searched the /etc folder for the smtp server being logged in /var/log/messages and it appears there are other files that I also need to update

/etc/ssmtp/ssmtp.conf.rpmsave
/etc/ssmtp/ssmtp.conf

Once I have updated the ports of the server in these files, the mail now tries to attempt to connect to the correct port